# Re-using an Ionic Example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to reuse this example of ionic http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbqqEb , when I try to replicate this sample code in my local I keep getting the below error. I replace the app.js with the js and index.html with the HTML code.

below is app.js

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
      url: "/check-in",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/check-in.html",
          controller: "CheckinCtrl"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
      url: "/attendees",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/attendees.html",
          controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.attendees = [
    { firstname: 'Nicolas', lastname: 'Cage' },
    { firstname: 'Jean-Claude', lastname: 'Van Damme' },
    { firstname: 'Keanu', lastname: 'Reeves' },
    { firstname: 'Steven', lastname: 'Seagal' },
    { firstname: 'varun', lastname: 'bhavsar' },
  ];

  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
})

.controller('CheckinCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showForm = true;

  $scope.shirtSizes = [
    { text: 'Large', value: 'L' },
    { text: 'Medium', value: 'M' },
    { text: 'Small', value: 'S' }
  ];

  $scope.attendee = {};
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if(!$scope.attendee.firstname) {
      alert('Info required');
      return;
    }
    $scope.showForm = false;
    $scope.attendees.push($scope.attendee);
  };

})

.controller('AttendeesCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.activity = [];
  $scope.arrivedChange = function(attendee) {
    var msg = attendee.firstname + ' ' + attendee.lastname;
    msg += (!attendee.arrived ? ' has arrived, ' : ' just left, '); 
    msg += new Date();
    $scope.activity.push(msg);
    if($scope.activity.length > 3) {
      $scope.activity.splice(0, 1);
    }
  };

});
```

below is html

```
<html ng-app="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Side Menus123</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content> 

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ul class="list">
              <!-- Note each link has the 'menu-close' attribute so the menu auto closes when clicking on one of these links -->
              <a href="#/event/check-in" class="item" menu-close>Check-in</a>
              <a href="#/event/attendees" class="item" menu-close>Attendees</a>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Welcome">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>Swipe to the right to reveal the left menu.</p>
          <p>(On desktop click and drag from left to right)</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/check-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Event Check-in">
        <ion-content>
          <form class="list" ng-show="showForm">
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Attendee Info
            </div>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="attendee.firstname">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="attendee.lastname">
            </label>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Shirt Size
            </div>
            <ion-radio ng-repeat="shirtSize in shirtSizes"
                       ng-value="shirtSize.value"
                       ng-model="attendee.shirtSize">
              {{ shirtSize.text }}
            </ion-radio>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Lunch
            </div>
            <ion-toggle ng-model="attendee.vegetarian">
              Vegetarian
            </ion-toggle>
            <div class="padding">
              <button class="button button-block" ng-click="submit()">Checkin</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <div ng-hide="showForm">
            <pre ng-bind="attendee | json"></pre> 
            <a href="#/event/attendees">View attendees</a>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/attendees.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Event Attendees">
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list">
            <ion-toggle ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | orderBy:'firstname' | orderBy:'lastname'"
                        ng-model="attendee.arrived"
                        ng-change="arrivedChange(attendee)">
              {{ attendee.firstname }}
              {{ attendee.lastname }}
            </ion-toggle>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Activity
            </div>
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="msg in activity">
              {{ msg }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:13249)
>       at assertArg (ionic.bundle.js:14951)
>       at assertArgFn (ionic.bundle.js:14961)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:22156
>       at setupControllers (ionic.bundle.js:21218)
>       at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21258)
>       at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20722)
>       at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20726)
>       at publicLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20597)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:14816(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25511ident.$get @ ionic.bundle.js:22290parent.$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29128bootstrapApply @ ionic.bundle.js:14814invoke @ ionic.bundle.js:17631doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:14812bootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:14832angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:14726(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:41540trigger @ ionic.bundle.js:16177eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16452

Comment: it looks like MainCtrl is not found, are you sure the .js files are imported correctly?

Comment: yes I copied it couple of times to make sure.

Comment: looking at the codepen the html file does not contain a reference to the js files containing the controller definitions. Using it as it is in the codepen will generate errors. You must add it yourself.

Comment: you mean to seperate the controllers in controller.js?

Comment: do you know what controller definations I have to include? I just getting started with Angular

Comment: no, codepen does some magic to run the content of the JS tab. If you plan to use that code outside of codepen you will need to import the js file using a script tag.

Comment: I already imported that file "app.js" I just updated the question with my html code.

Comment: you need to define a starting module, you can not leave ng-app empty. check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** define starting module defined in the ng-app directive.

```
<html ng-app="">
```

Should be

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
```